# Mysql select in another table when not exist

Tags: mysql

I have two tables, name tbl_siswa and tbl_tentor.

Both have an uniq id, in tbl_siswa called id_siswa and in tbl_tentor called tbl_tentor.

how to check if an input ID is from tbl_tentor or tbl_siswa in one query.

i can make this with PHP and mysql, but i need this only in mysql..

Comment: And have you tried anything? please read [this article](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: have you try join try th e sql joins

Comment: Hint: Create a stored procedure that checks if an Id is from one table or another

Comment: "Both have an uniq id, in tbl_siswa called id_siswa and in tbl_tentor called tbl_tentor"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fastest way is by a `union`:

```
select id_siswa as id
from tbl_siswa
where id_siswa = ?
union
select id_tentor
from tbl_tentor
where id_tentor = ?
```

Note that you will either get one row or no rows. Even if the id appears in both tables, you will only get one row because `union` removes duplicate rows.